# Trigger CSS rule when element contents starts wrapping

Tags: css

I can use the following CSS to make something happen if the browser width is less than 800px.

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 800px)
{
    #content
    {
        width: auto;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make some CSS happen to a certain element if the height of that specific element is greater than a certain value?

My goal is to have special CSS trigger if the contents of an elements starts to wrap because of too narrow browser width, without being dependent on a hard coded max-width.

---

**More specific example**

```
<h2>Long title followed by <span class="subtitle">a subtitle</span></h2>


.subtitle
{
    margin-left: .7em;
    font-size: .6em;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 600px)
{
    .subtitle
    {
        vertical-align: super;
        &:before
        {
            content: '\A';
            white-space: pre;
        }
    }
}
```

What I need is that the `.subtitle` should get `vertical-align: super` if it wraps to another line than the rest of the title. I currently do this manually when the browser shrinks to a certain width, but the problem is that some headers are longer than this and I'd like it to happen automatically whenever a header wraps, independent of the browser width.

Comment: Could you try using `max-height` to trigger on all normal circumstances, and another rule that would automatically run when the height is greater than that `max-height`?

Comment: if that element's width depends (relative to) on the width of the viewport, I think it's possible.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22185433/rules-to-apply-to-a-wrapped-float

Comment: @KingKing The elements width depends only on its content unfortunately.

Comment: Are you looking for a pure CSS solution, or would a little JS be acceptable?

Comment: Pure CSS would be preferred, but a little JS may also be acceptable if it's small and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Media queries unfortunately only work relative to screen size (and a few other screen based properties). What you require is something the lines of the proposed '[Element Query](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/06/25/media-queries-are-not-the-answer-element-query-polyfill/)'.

This is a common problem in CSS. One solution is to detect a change in height on the container (the `<h1>` in your example). It would have to detect against a hard coded pixel value and when greater than that threshold toggle a class.
You have the added complication that the change in CSS you require will affect the height of the very container you are testing against, possibly creating a circular loop of test and change. This is one of the most difficult challenges of 'Queries on Elements'.